# Downloading pdf plot using shiny app after reading excel files

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

As, I am new to shiny apps need some assistance, uploading excel file and generating table output in shiny app works fine, but can't able to download the plot to a pdf format 
Here is my code

```
library(shiny)
library(openxlsx)
library(lattice)

runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      titlePanel("plots"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          fileInput('file1', 'Choose xlsx file',
                    accept = c(".xlsx")),
          tags$hr(),
          downloadButton('down',"download plot")
        ),
        mainPanel(
          tableOutput('contents'),
        plotOutput('plot'))
      )
    ),
    server = function(input, output){
      output$contents <- renderTable({
        inFile <- input$file1

        if(is.null(inFile))
          return(NULL)
        else
        read.xlsx(inFile$datapath)
      })

      plotInput <- reactive({
        df <- input$file1
        xyplot(df[,2]~df[,1],df(),xlim=c(0,10),ylim=c(0,100),type = "b")
      })

      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        print(plotInput())
      })

      output$down <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function(){paste("plot",".pdf",sep=".") },
        content = function(file) {
          pdf(file)
         xyplot(df[,2]~df[,1],df(),xlim=c(0,10),ylim=c(0,100),type = "b")
          dev.off()
        }
      )
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: when try to download the plot the error pops up can any one guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that in some parts of your code you were accessing a dynamic data frame via `df()` but you had never defined it.

In this kind of problem, it is best to create a reactive data frame, say, `df` which contains the uploaded data and is passed to other reactive parts of the code via `df()`.

---

**Full example:**

```
library(shiny)
library(openxlsx)
library(lattice)

runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      titlePanel("plots"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          fileInput('file1', 'Choose xlsx file',
                    accept = c(".xlsx")),
          tags$hr(),
          downloadButton('down',"download plot")
        ),
        mainPanel(
          tableOutput('contents'),
          plotOutput('plot'))
      )
    ),
    server = function(input, output){


      df <- reactive({
        inFile <- input$file1
        req(inFile) # require that inFile is available (is not NULL) 
                    # (a user has uploaded data)

        # read.xlsx(inFile$datapath)
        head(iris, 10)
      })

      output$contents <- renderTable({
        # access uploaded data via df()
        df()
      })

      plotInput <- reactive({
        df <- df()
        xyplot(df[,2]~df[,1], df ,xlim=c(0,10),ylim=c(0,100),type = "b")
      })

      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        plotInput()
      })

      output$down <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function(){paste("plot",".pdf",sep=".") },
        content = function(file) {
          pdf(file)
          #xyplot(df[,2]~df[,1],df(),xlim=c(0,10),ylim=c(0,100),type = "b")

          # you have to print the plot so that you can open pdf file
          print(plotInput())
          dev.off()
        }
      )
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: can we print unique individual plots in pdf based on ID's and download the file